# Pass array from view to models in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

function income_reports : model

```
$this->db->where('tbl_sub_products.sub_product_id',
$this->input->post('product_cat'));
```

Hi, I am kind of new to codeigniter .Some one can please explain me how we can change this code to grab multiple inputs from the view.

It takes only one value at ones. If we select multiple values it shows as an empty array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <select name="product_cat" multiple="multiple" size="8"> 
 <?php if (isset($product_cat)) : foreach ($product_cat as $row) : ?> <option value="<?php echo $row->sub_product_id; ?>"> <?php echo $row->sub_product_name; ?> </option> <?php endforeach; ?> <?php endif; ?> 
 </select>
```

to

```
<select name="product_cat[]" multiple="multiple" size="8"> 
<?php if (isset($product_cat)) : foreach ($product_cat as $row) : ?> <option value="<?php echo $row->sub_product_id; ?>"> <?php echo $row->sub_product_name; ?>  </option> <?php endforeach; ?> <?php endif; ?> 
</select>
```

In controller or model, Your Query should be ::         $this->db->**where_in**('tbl_sub_products.sub_product_id',$this->input->post('product_cat'));  *PS: $this->input->post('product_cat') is an array.*

Comment: PS : $this->input->post('product_cat') is an array. Hope these help you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Associative Array.

```
$array = array('name !=' => $name, 'id <' => $id, 'date >' => $date);

$this->db->where($array);
```

If you have `OR`/`AND` associations, then try

```
$this->db->where( "(loginid = '$username' OR email = '$username') AND (status = 'Active')" );
```

Comment: `<select name="product_cat" multiple="multiple" size="8">
    <?php
                                if (isset($product_cat)) :
                                    foreach ($product_cat as $row) :
                                        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row->sub_product_id; ?>">
            <?php echo $row->sub_product_name; ?>
        </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
</select>`